# Links section for HTML?

Tags: html, css

It looks like the one at the very bottom of this page:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx

is there an easier way to create boxes and put them side by side?

Mine looks like a staircase going downwards by 380px for each

here's my source code:

```
    <!--External Links-->   <div id="external_links">
    <div>
        <ul style="height:380px; width:240px; max-width:240px;" id="Rowone">
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="height:380px; width:240px; max-width:240px;" id="Rowtwo">
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul style="height:380px; width:240px; max-width:240px;" id="Rowthree">
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why is every link contained in a list on its own instead of a list item? Wouldn't it make more sense to put all the links in one `ul` and have each of them contained in a `li`? (No need for these two divs either)

Comment: Do you want them under each other in one column? or side by side? ( what from your example link do you want to replicate here?)

Comment: Is this the effect you want? http://jsfiddle.net/LpMfZ/

Comment: You are right @Sergio, sorry. I was distracted by there only being a single li in each ul. Floating or `display: inline-block` can be used to sit the ul next to each other.

Comment: @AndrewGibson, yes, `display: inline-block;` is even better. I changed :)

Comment: Thanks everyone :), Yeah the two divs are because this was given to me by another coder and he told me not to delete them... he said he'd need it for something else :P
@Sergio Thanks, yeah that's along the lines of my desire, I have it now :D Thanks

Comment: @MomoCoolBreezyKitty, you are welcome. Next time you post a question stay around because people here have fast questions and its good if you are there to answer them when they come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets reorganize and simplify your code a bit.  I removed the extra `<ul>` tags - these would prevent the links from displaying next to one another.

```
<!--External Links-->   <div id="external_links">
<div>
    <ul style="height:380px;" id="Rowone">
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now add a little CSS definition for the `<li>` tag.

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Note that I removed the width rules from your remaining `<ul>` tag - it wasn't wide enough to permit all three links to display side by side.  Here's a JSfiddle to demonstrate the code in action.  http://jsfiddle.net/VAP3X/

Comment: Thanks, I found another way to do it though, looking at the bottom of this page. BUT your way works better so Imma go with that, thanks so much ^_^

Comment: There are often many ways to accomplish the same layout.  I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Oh... 1 more thing it pnly displays 2 lines... I think it may be my css problem, thanks anyways ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I supose this might be what you are looking for:
(check this http://jsfiddle.net/LpMfZ/)

```
<!--External Links-->
<div id="external_links">
<ul id="Rowone">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="Rowtwo">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul id="Rowthree">
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://www.andymark.com/" title="AndyMarks - Distributor"><h3>Andy Mark</h3></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And in your CSS file:

```
#external_links ul {
display: inline-block;
height:380px;
width:140px;
max-width:240px;
}
#external_links ul li {
list-style:none;
line-height: 0px;
}
```